# PHP Search Form with Specific Filtering

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, search

I am currently in the process of learning the basics of HTML, PHP and SQL in my own time to try and further myself at work.

I have set myself the challenge of producing a website which is based upon a Books company. I have successfully constructed pages that show a list of all books which is connected to my books DB. I have also created a function within the list of books to dynamically show extra information on a specific book when selected.

So far it has been ok but now I have been stuck for sometime on the ability of a user to search the database of books on specific search criteria.

for example I want to be able to select a specific search criteria from a drop down list eg book title, author etc and for the user to enter it into the linked search box and for it to return the values from the database. please find attached my code so far and apologies for any obvious mistakes as I have just started learning this stuff....

Search Form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--OVERALL WRAPPER CONTAINER-->
<div id="wrapper">

<!--OUTER CONTAINER-->
<div id="container">

 <!--HEADER CONTAINER-->
<div id="header"><!--LOGO PATH GOES HERE--><img src="../../../Web Design/websitebanner1.jpg" width="960" height="200" alt="Northumbria Book Company"></div>



<!--NAVIGATION CONTAINER-->
<div id="navContainer">
<center><ul>

<li><a href=".html"> 
<u>Home</u></a></li>

<li><u><a href=".html">Search</a></u></li>

<li><u><a href=".html">Credits</a></u></li>

<li><u><a href=".php">Books</a>

</u></li>

</ul>
</center>
</div>



<!--MAIN CONTENT CONTAINER-->
<div id="mainContainer">
<form id="SeachByCategory" action="SearchBookDB" method="get">
 <h1>Search For a Book</h1>
 <select name="category">
        <option value="bookISBN">Book ISBN</option>
        <option value="bookTitle">Book Title</option>
        <option value="bookYear">Book Year</option>
        <option value="pubID">Publisher</option>
        <option value="catID">Category</option>
    </select>

<label>Search: <input type="text" name="BookSearch" /></label>
 <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Find Books" />
</p>
</form>

</div>
<div id="footer">
<div align="center">



<ul>
<li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div></div></div>
</body>
```

Database query:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>

<body>

<?php
include 'database_conn.php';

$bookTitleSearch = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'bookTitle') ? $_GET    ['bookTitle']: null;

$sql = "SELECT * from nbc_book WHERE bookTitle = '%$bookTitleSearch%'"; 

$queryresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult)){
echo $row['bookTitle'];
}

mysql_free_result($queryresult);
mysql_close($conn);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try? `$sql = "SELECT * from nbc_book WHERE bookTitle LIKE '%$bookTitleSearch%'";`

Comment: just tried that and it returns a HTTP 404

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * from nbc_book WHERE bookTitle LIKE '%$bookTitleSearch%'";` Try this instead.

Comment: What is difference between yours and mine query? Since OP got an error. @AkramFares

Comment: My bad, i didn't notice.

Comment: does it look like my form is correctly linked to my db search if I am returning a http404?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<?php
include 'database_conn.php';

$bookTitleSearch = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'bookTitle') ? $_GET['bookTitle']: null;

$sql = "SELECT * from nbc_book WHERE bookTitle = '%$bookTitleSearch%'"; 

$queryresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult)){
    echo $row['bookTitle'];
}

mysql_free_result($queryresult);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Why your form action is this way?  `<form id="SeachByCategory" action="SearchBookDB" method="get">` shouldnt it be: `action="SearchBookDB.php"`

Comment: added my full html code to original comment and I have now changed the action which returns :Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/unn_w13045125/public_html/SearchBookDB.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/unn_w13045125/public_html/SearchBookDB.php on line 24

Comment: So, your expected work has been done with these 2 warnings? Am I right?

Comment: I thinkt he two warnings was because I wasn't consistent with mysqli naming convention, once I changed this and I search for a book title I am returned with a blank screen

Comment: You are doing `mysql` when you should do `mysqli`. Change last 2 linees to `mysqli_free_result($queryresult);` and `mysqli_close($conn);`

Comment: I have done this as mentioned in my previous comment but now I am returned with a blank screen.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` on top of php page and tell me the error.

Comment: which page will I put this on the form or the query and what section?

Comment: The page on which you have written PHP code. The query page. Most probably `SearchBookDB.php` page.

Comment: Add something like: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); 
include 'database_conn.php';........` blaaah blaahh code...

Comment: prints nothing im afraid

Comment: Well sorry I cant help you furthur as I am not sure what excatly is your problem, Check `database_conn.php` please to made sure you are using `mysqli`.